# Conditional sentences not starting with "if"

Tags: word-choice, word-order, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, bare-conditional

> Were I rich, I would live on Long Island.
>   If I were rich, I would live on Long Island.

Is the first sentence still used, or is used in particular contexts (in example, to give emphasis to the sentence)?

Comment: And, in the past tense: *If I had been rich* vs *Had I been rich*.

Comment: Other conditionals not starting with "if", though not that sentence: *Should you find yourself in trouble*, or *In case you*, or *In the event that*, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rarely used nowadays (in the US at least).  It will usually come off as sounding stilted in everyday speech, but possibly more educated/sophisticated in formal speaking and writing (but even then, should probably be used sparingly).